Describing the volatility skew with a set of options
Say you have a set of options data, and you filter the dataset based on certain criteria such as the bid-ask spread, open volume etc. and you end up with a set of liquid options based on said criteria.
If your options dataset contains liquid ITM/ATM/OTM calls and puts, would it be wrong to describe the volatility skew using the ITM calls and puts as well?
If that is the case, should I manually remove these ITM options?
Because I usually see that only OTM and ATM options being used to describe the skew and for some reason my filtering algorithm did not remove the ITM options (or detect them as illiquid, which is the normal case).

Does put-call parity imply one of these is redundant anyway? ITM call = OTM put at same strike.

It is not necessarily wrong to include ITM options in your analysis of the volatility skew, but it may not provide as much insight as focusing on the ATM and OTM options. The volatility skew is often most pronounced in OTM options, as they are typically more influenced by market sentiment and perceived risk.

Answering my question for anyone's interest in this topic. I took indirect inspiration from this post:
How does an option's time value depend on moneyness?
On whether to include (perhaps more so for deep) ITM options to describe your volatility skew - my suggestion is no.
The reason for this is because, as an ITM (OTM) option matures, the option price increases (decreases) by a lot (little). Assuming the underlying spot is constant, this large increase in option price for an ITM option corresponds to a large spike in IV as compared to a smaller spike for OTM variants. Therefore, to ensure the time-stability of an option-implied volatility skew, it might be wiser to remove ITM options.
